# Can we get the applet code in client side

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet

I have a legacy applet code with me. It is jar file. 
During the applet execution, will the jar be downloaded to client side??
it has some important operation, will any one be able to decompile the jar file and get the required information from JAR?

Answer (score 1):

> During the applet execution, will the jar be downloaded to client side. it has some important operation, will any one be able to decompile the jar file and get the required information from JAR?

Yes. Anyone can decompile the jar file, and if it contains any sensitive information; they can recover it. The same is true with other languages, client code (by definition) *executes* on the client (*debuggers*, *decompilers* and *disassemblers* are widely available tools).